# Swift, Foundation, Combine

Tags: swift, import, frameworks, combine, foundation

The Foundation framework in Swift imports Combine:

[image]

Why can't I use Combine when I only `import Foundation`?

By comparison, I can use the Foundation framework just by importing "UIKit" framework (which imports "Foundation" internally).

I'm trying to remove duplicated imports.

Comment: Please update your question with a minimal example of code, as text, that demonstrates your issue. Show how you are trying to use "Combine" simply by importing Foundation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually want imports to work transitively like this.

Many libraries want to have a small public interface, while doing lots of stuff internally that they don't want others to worry about. It bloats your namespace, importing more things than you usually care for, which then slows IDE and compiler performance. (e.g. there will be more type available to look up).

When you do want it, there's the private `@_exported` attribute, which is what UIKit is using to re-export Foundation to its callers.

```swift
@_exported import ModuleName
```

Comment: I'm curious how this answers the vague question. I had no trouble compiling some Swift code that used some Combine protocols while only importing Foundation.

Comment: I couldn't call "AnyCancellable" without import Combine

Comment: @I_love_gallic This is why you need to post your attempted code in your question.

Comment: @HangarRash Agree. This might be platform-specific, too, as these frameworks are layered differently between pre-Monterey macOS, post-Monterey macOS, and Linux.